# Collect Azure Netapp Volume metrics

Tags: azure, netapp

Right now I'm viewing the Azure NetApp volume metrics using Azure Portal metrics dashboard.I can see only one month old data. I'm planning to collect this data and save into SQL table. So that I have the history of this data (i.e. more than 30 days). Is there a powershell commands that I can use?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVmIw.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Azure NetApp Files: PowerShell One-Liners](https://anfcommunity.com/2021/08/03/azure-netapp-files-powershell-one-liners/), you can use `Get-AzMetric`, provide `StartTime`  and `EndTime` to get the history of data.

Try the following code snippet taken from the document, for example:

```
Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like 'Microsoft.NetApp/netAppAccounts/capacityPools/volumes'} 
| Get-AzNetAppFilesVolume | Select-Object @{Name='ShortName'; Expression={$_.Name.split('/')[2]}}, @{Name='SizeGiB'; 
Expression={$_.UsageThreshold / 1024 / 1024 / 1024}},
 @{Name='ConsumedGiB'; 
Expression={[math]::Round($((Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $_.Id -MetricName 'VolumeLogicalSize'
 -StartTime $(get-date).AddMinutes(-15) -EndTime $(get-date) -TimeGrain 00:5:00 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue 
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average) | Measure-Object -average).average / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2)}} | Format-Table
```

You can refer to [PowerShell and CLI for Azure NetApp Files](https://anfcommunity.com/2020/09/11/powershell-and-cli-for-azure-netapp-files/) and [Azure NetApp Files metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/monitor-azure-netapp-files)